# Azure Logic App - Recurring Trigger Not Recurring

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-scheduler

I have a simple Azure logic app that starts with a trigger step, which is "When One or More BLOBS are Added" to a specific Azure storage container. It has an interval setting to check for new files every 3 minutes.  It then calls one more step to send a message to a service bus queue. In My Logic App Designer there is a "Run" button,  and in the Overview panel of the Logic App, there is a "Run Trigger" command. If I run either of these from the Azure Portal my job runs continually as expected.

My issue is that once I leave the portal, my logic app no longer runs. I assumed that the Interval setting on the Trigger Step (Step 1) of every 3 minutes meant just that. I read that I can put a Scheduler step as step 1, but how does that interact with the 3 minute interval setting of the BLOB trigger?

My goal is to have the logic app run every 3 minutes, looking for any new files placed in the BLOB container since the last run, and then sending the service bus message as a step 2. Note that I also have an Azure Scheduler that I can use if that is a better solution (i.e. triggering the job wit ha web hook).

I appreciate the help!!

Comment: If you navigate to the Logic App's overview blade in the Azure portal, there should be a section called "Trigger history" on the right-hand side. Do you see "Skipped" entry showing in the list, with 3 minutes in between?

Comment: Derek, thank you for your response. I am not 100% sure why, but it seems to be working properly now. The trigger history did not report any skips. I will keep an eye on things to see how it goes.

Comment: Hi @DanielG, did you figure out any reason as to why your logic app was not automatically triggering? I have a similar issue. I have a reoccurrence set up for 8am every day, but it never triggers automatically. The trigger history does not show skips, it only shows my manual triggers.

Comment: My logic app is working as expected now. In all honesty, I think I was just misinterpreting the way it worked. Clicking the "Run Trigger" button runs it on-demand. If the status is "Enabled", and the "Summary" section is as you expect, I think it is in fact running. I also had some code errors (failures) that I corrected. Your process may be running but failing (i.e. a code error), and the Logic App just does not handle that too well. Is this still an issue for you? Sorry for slow response...

Comment: An architectural note on your solution is that it would probably be better to listen for events on the blob container through Event Grid rather than doing a diff on an interval.